# Vectors that form basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider the following set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3:$
>
> $u_0 = (1,2,0),~ u_1 = (1,2,1), ~u_2 = (2,3,0), ~u_3 = (4,6,1)$
>
> Explain why each of the two subsets $B_0 = \left\{u_0, u_2,
>  u_3\right\}$ and $B_1 = \left\{u_1, u_2, u_3\right\}$ forms a basis of
>    $\mathbb{R}^3$. If we write $[\mathbf{x}]_0$ and $[\mathbf{x}]_1$ for the coordinates of the vector $\mathbf{x}$ in terms of these two basis, find the precise transition matrix which inter-relates these two sets of coordinates. If $\mathbf{x} = 4\mathbf{e}_1+4\mathbf{e}_3$, what are $\mathbf [\mathbf{x}]_0$ and $[\mathbf{x}]_1$?

Writing the vectors of the subset $B_0$ as the columns of a matrix we have:

$\mathbf{A}_0: = \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&4  \\ 
2&3&6  \\ 
0&0 &1  
\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&4  \\ 
0&-1&-4  \\ 
0&0 &1  
\end{pmatrix} \implies \det(\mathbf{A}_0) =(1)(-1)(1) =  -1 $

As the columns of a $3 \times 3$ matrix whose determinant is non-zero, these vectors form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3.$

Similarly, writing the vectors of the subset $B_1$ as the columns of a matrix we have:

$\mathbf{A}_1: = \begin{pmatrix}
1&1&2  \\ 
3&2&6  \\ 
0&1 &1 
\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}
1&1&2  \\ 
0&-1&0  \\ 
0&0 &1  
\end{pmatrix} \implies \det(\mathbf{A}_1) =(1)(-1)(1) =  -1 $

As the columns of a $3 \times 3$ matrix whose determinant is non-zero, these vectors form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3.$

I don't know what it wants me to do beyond this point however. Could someone please explain what a transition matrix is?

Comment: Do you perhaps know what change of basis matrix is?

Comment: $A_1$ looks incorrect to me.

Comment: @amd I just rechecked it and can't find a mistake. $R_2 \to R_2-3R_1$ then $R_3 \to R_3 +R_2$ gives the reduced matrix.

Comment: The reduced matrix isn’t the issue. The original matrix is. Its first and third columns don’t match any of the given vectors, so $\mathbf A_1$ certainly isn’t “the vectors of the subset $B1$ as the columns of a matrix.”

Comment: @amd, Thanks for catching that! I should have said $$\mathbf{A}_1: = \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&4  \\ 
2&3&6  \\ 
1&0 &1 
\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&4  \\ 
0&-1&-2  \\ 
0&0 &1  
\end{pmatrix} \implies \det(\mathbf{A}_1) =(1)(-1)(1) =  -1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given vector $x$
$$ 
x = 4 e_1+ 4 e_3
$$
can be represented according the first or the second basis too.
\begin{align}
x 
&= x_1^{(0)} b_1^{(0)} + x_2^{(0)} b_2^{(0)} + x_3^{(0)} b_3^{(0)}
= (x_1^{(0)},x_2^{(0)},x_3^{(0)})^T = [x]_0 \\
&= x_1^{(1)} b_1^{(1)} + x_2^{(1)} b_2^{(1)} + x_3^{(1)} b_3^{(1)}
= (x_1^{(1)},x_2^{(1)},x_3^{(1)})^T = [x]_1
\end{align}
This gives a set $[x]_i$ of coordinates, a coordinate vector, for each basis. You are asked to give the matrix $T$, which would transform the first set into the second set of coordinates.
$$
[x]_1 = T [x]_0
$$

**Solution:**

From $B_0$ to standard basis $e_i$ we get via the matrix
$$
A_0 = 
(u_0, u_2, u_3) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 4 \\
2 & 3 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
From $B_1$ to standard basis we get via the matrix
$$
A_1 = 
(u_1, u_2, u_3) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 4 \\
2 & 3 & 6 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
From $B_0$ to $B_1$ we get by going from $B_0$ to standard basis via $A_0$ and from standard basis to $B_1$ via $A_1^{-1}$:
\begin{align}
T &= A_1^{-1} A_0 \\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
We have 
\begin{align}
[x]_0 &= A_0^{-1} [x] \\
&=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
-3 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & -1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\
0 \\
4
\end{pmatrix} \\
&=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
-12 \\
0 \\
4
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
[x]_1 &= A_1^{-1} [x] \\
&=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
-3 &  2 & 0 \\
-4 &  3 & -2 \\
 3 & -2 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
4 \\
0 \\
4
\end{array}
\right)
\\
&=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
-12 \\
-24 \\
16
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! I've found two transition matrices:

$$T = \begin{pmatrix}
3&1&6  \\ 
-1&0&-4  \\ 
0&0 &1  
\end{pmatrix}$$

So that $[x]_1 = T [x]_0$

And $$T' = \begin{pmatrix}
0&-1&-4  \\ 
1&3&6  \\ 
0&0 &1  
\end{pmatrix}$$

So that $[x]_0 = T' [x]_1$


However, they map the coordinates from one non-standard basis to next, so I'm never in a position to use the given fact $x = 4 e_1+ 4 e_3$. It's possible that I completely misunderstand what's going on, however.

Comment: The matrix has to work for arbitrary $x$. The special $x$ was given for the last part of the task, calculating its coordinates regarding the $B_i$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been struggling with this question for hours and hours! I'll study your post, and put it in my notes! I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @GGG Notice that, since the two bases differ only in their first vectors, you can immediately write down two of the columns of the transition matrix.